# Effective Branch cut

Tags: contour-integration

I have problems understanding how to get to the "effective Brach cut" in the top answer of this post: 
[Dog Bone Contour Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261515/dog-bone-contour-integral/1261579#1261579?newreg=56ed8b85206b4b9583333bf72e4e80b4) 
?

The answer says that one has a Branch cut for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z-1}}$ at $(-\infty,1]$ and for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z+1}}$ at $(-\infty,-1]$ and then one gets the "effective" Branch cut for $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)}}$ at $[-1,+1]$.

I don't understand this. Why is the function $f(z)$ suddenly defined on $(-\infty,-1)$? What cancels out ? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626351/) may prove relevant, as may this [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329029/).

Comment: Thank you!This was helpful!